# Inserting Vertical Space in Pandoc Markdown

Tags: pandoc

Is it possible to insert a extra vertical space using Pandoc flavored Markdown? Something that would show up as a blank line in a Word document or a `<br>` in HTML or \vspace in LaTeX. Or anything equivalent?

My problem is that I don't want a title for my reference list, but this puts my references too close to the preceding paragraph in both Word and in LaTeX.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

One way to do it is to insert a paragraph containing just a nonbreaking space.

You can use either of these forms in pandoc:

```
\_ (where "_" signifies a space)

&nbsp;
```

Comment: @YannickWurm Make sure the backslash is followed by a space. ( \<space><newline> )

Comment: How can I achieve this with eclipse (do not know the plugin, but there is a preview tab) or retext?

Comment: I am using markdown to make a revealjs slideshow in HTML and only the `&nbsp;` solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For pdf, do the following (replace the s with space): \s\s